# vscode vue debugging with chrome and official vue recipies

Tags: vue.js, webpack, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I have been at this for days now of internet searching and decided to post what I have in hopes of finding someone who can figure out what is going on here.  I have tried and examined the output of every possible iteration of sourcemappathoverrides.  This seems to be the main issues with the debugging recipes from vue.  Those have to be modified for your code structure.  I have also tried changing the configs in babel, webpack, babel-loader and all of the internal vscode files.  Right now I have it so that I can reliable jump into breakpoints if I turn off the use preview javascript debugger in vscode.
While this works it takes minutes (I am not exaggerating) to hit a breakpoint in vscode.  While this is going on vscode is completely unresponsive. when the default debugger (use preview) is enabled the breakpoints that get hit in the code are instantly hit but not where I placed them originally.  Once the code starts you are unable to put breakpoints in many locations.  I know that this indicates a sourcemap issue but the same sourcemaps work perfectly when reverting to the old javascript debugger.  This is my current configuration.

[image]

This is my webpack config (I just recently added the babel-loader section which doesn't make any difference)

// webpack.config.js

```js
    module.exports = {
      // ...
      entry: {
        "app": "src/main.js"
      },
      //mode: 'development',
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                '@vue/app'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    };
```

This my vue.config (I have tried changing publicpath, compress, chaingwebpackoptions with no luck)

```js
    const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
    
    module.exports = {
    
      pages: {
        index: {
          entry: 'src/index.js',
          template: 'public/index.html',
          filename: 'index.html'
        }
      },
      devServer: {
        clientLogLevel: 'warning',
        hot: true,
        contentBase: 'dist',
        compress: false,
        open: true,
        overlay: { warnings: false, errors: true },
        publicPath: '/',
        quiet: true,
        watchOptions: {
          poll: false,
          //I want to be able to jump into node_modules to debug
          ignored: /node_modules/
        }
      },
      chainWebpack: config => {
        config.plugins.delete('prefetch-index'),
        config.module
          .rule('vue')
            .use('vue-loader')
              .tap(args => {
                args.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve'
              })
      },
      productionSourceMap: false,
      assetsDir: './assets/',
      configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map',
        plugins: [
          new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
              { from: 'src/assets/img', to: 'assets/img' },
              { from: 'src/assets/logos', to: 'assets/logos' },
              { from: 'src/assets/fonts', to: 'assets/fonts' }
            ],
          }),
        ]
      }
    }
```

this is my jsonconfig (just recently commented out the webpack.config. It doesn't matter either way)

```
    {
        /*"include": [
          "webpack.config.js"    
        ],*/
        "compilerOptions": {
          "sourceMap": true
        }
      }
```

my babel config (originally I had no "env" section.  Adding this made no difference)

```js
    module.exports = {
      "env":{
        "development":{
          "sourceMaps":true,
          "retainLines":true,
        }
      },
      presets: [
        '@vue/app'
      ]
    }
```

this is my launch config (this is where I spent the most time.  I tired every combination under the sun of sourcemappathoverrides and webroot with or without /src).  The sourcemap binding in the logs appear to be correct but breakpoints jump around from where they are dropped or aren't able to be set at all.

```js
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "trace":"verbose",
          //also right click on your chrome icon and add this to the target field (--remote-debugging-port=9222)
          "port": 9222,
          "name": "vuejs: chrome",
          "url": "http://localhost:8080",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "breakOnLoad": true,
                "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                  "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                  "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                  "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
                },
          "preLaunchTask": "vuejs: start"
        }
      ]
      }
```

and finally my task to launch chrome after the app starts running

```js
    {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
          {
            "label": "vuejs: start",
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "serve",
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
              "reveal": "always",
              "panel": "shared",
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
              "owner": "typescript",
              "fileLocation": "relative",
              "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^([^\\s].*)\\((\\d+|\\,\\d+|\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+)\\):\\s+(error|warning|info)\\s+(TS\\d+)\\s*:\\s*(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "location": 2,
                "severity": 3,
                "code": 4,
                "message": 5
              },
              "background": {
                "activeOnStart": true,
                "beginsPattern": ".",
                "endsPattern": "App running at",
              }
          }
    
          }
          
        ]
    }
```